# Possible misuse of evt.target.name. "Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties."

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So far this program is supposed to make an child object visible when the parent object is moused over, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm in a little over my head here. Here's my code:

```
var iconCompArray:Array = new Array();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveMouse);
addIcons();

function addIcons():void
{
    var iconComp:IconComp = new IconComp();
    iconComp.x = stage.stageWidth/4;
    iconComp.y = stage.stageHeight/4;
    iconComp.iconImage.gotoAndStop(2);
    iconComp.iconHighlight.visible = false;
    iconComp.iconTitle.text = "Program X";
    iconCompArray.push(iconComp);
    addChild(iconComp);
}

function moveMouse(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < iconCompArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (evt.target.name == iconCompArray[i])
        {
            iconCompArray[i].iconHighlight.visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

A new "iconComp" is pulled from the library and added to the stage through the iconCompArray. The idea was that when you mouse over the icon, a blue box would appear around it (iconHighlight.visible). But for some reason, what I have here doesn't work. I think I may have used evt.target.name incorrectly but I can't find a solution. Here's the error message that appears in the output:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at as3_fla::MainTimeline/addIcons()
    at as3_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Comment: When iconComp is created, are the properties iconImage, iconHighlight and iconTitle set, or are they uninitialized?  If they're not initialized, then any of the three middle lines in your addIcons function will be trying to access a property on null.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you get the problem seems to be in the addIcons functions. You should check that the name of all your movie clip's childs is correct. The movie clip's property mouseChildren should be set to false. Also, it would be probably better if you use MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT events instead of MOUSE_MOVE.

```
function addIcons():void
{
  var iconComp:IconComp = new IconComp();
  iconComp.x = stage.stageWidth / 4;
  iconComp.y = stage.stageHeight / 4;
  iconComp.iconImage.gotoAndStop(2);
  iconComp.iconHighlight.visible = false;
  iconComp.iconTitle.text = "Program X";
  iconComp.mouseChildren = false;

  iconComp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onIconOver);
  iconComp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onIconOut);

  iconCompArray.push(iconComp);
  addChild(iconComp);
}
```

And the event listeners should look like this:

```
function onIconOver(evt:MouseEvent):void {
  IconComp(evt.target).iconHighlight.visible = true;
}

function onIconOut(evt:MouseEvent):void {
  IconComp(evt.target).iconHighlight.visible = false;
}
```

You can also see the line of code that gives you that error if youy publish the swf in debug mode (Ctrl+Shift+Enter).

Comment: I've followed everything you said I should do. Unfortunately, the iconHighlight child object seems to be causing a lot of problems now, whereas the other child objects are not (iconTitle, iconImage). If I clear the code `iconComp.iconHighlight.visible = false;` from the addIcons function, then the program runs fine until I mouse over the icon. I've checked the object name and the AS Linkage and it all seems to match up, so I'm lost. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Have you tried creating another iconHighlight movieclip and replace it? There might be issues in the library.